# Convert a char inside a String to ASCII

Tags: c, string, char, ascii

I'm doing a mini C compiler for a Univeristy Project.

My problem is:

How can i obtain the ascii of the char inside the string?

The string is always in this format:
`"'{char}'"`

For example:

```
char* c1 = "'a'" #I want the ascii code of char: a
```

In this case, I can obtain the ascii code with the command `int(c1[1])`.

But if the case is:

```
char* c1 = "'\000'" #I want the ascii code of char: \000
```

How can I obtain the ascii code of this case?

Is it possible to obtain a generic function for all cases?

Comment: `(int)c2[1];` would do it.

Comment: `"'a'"` is an array of 4 chars. Which one do you want the ASCII code for?

Comment: Are you trying to write a little parser that can basically parse C-stryle character constants?  You can do that, but it won't involve something as basic as `atoi`.

Comment: I'm doing a C compiler. I want the ASCII code of char 'a' that is stored in a string. Is that any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the codes of characters, a simple way is

```
char c1 = '\0';
int c1_code = c1;

char c2 = 'a';
int c2_code = c2;

printf("%d %d\n", c1_code, c2_code);
```

On an ASCII system, this will print `0 97`.

But this is a little silly.  It would be simpler and more straightforward to just write

```
int c1_code = '\0';
int c2_code = 'a';
```

This works because of a super easy, super important basic definition in C:

> In C, a character is represented by a small integer corresponding to the value of that character in the machine's character set.

In some languages, you need special functions to convert back and forth between characters and cheir character-set values.  (I believe BASIC uses `CHR$` and `INT$`, or something.)  But in C, you don't need any special processing: a character basically just *is* its value.

If you want to find character values out of *strings* (not single characters, as I've shown so far), it's only a tiny bit more involved.  A string in C is just an array of characters, so you can do something like this:

char str3[] = "a";
   int c3_value = str2[0];    /* value of first character in string */

I can print character values even more simply like this:

```
printf("%d %d %d\n", 'a', 'b', 'c');
```

If I read a line of text from the user:

```
char line[100];
printf("type something:\n");
fgets(line, 100, stdin);
```

I can print the values of the first few characters like this:

```
printf("you typed:\n");
printf("%c = %d\n", line[0], line[0]);
printf("%c = %d\n", line[1], line[1]);
printf("%c = %d\n", line[2], line[2]);
```

If you're unfamiliar with C's character handling, I encourage you to write a little program like this and play with it.  For example, if I run that program and type "Hello, world!" into it, it will print

```
You typed:
H = 72
e = 101
l = 108
```

---

Perhaps you knew all of this.  Perhaps you really did want to do something like

```
char *c1 = "'\\000'";
```

meaning that `c1` is a *string* containing the six characters

```
' \ 0 0 0 '
```

and you want to interpret this string as the syntax of a C character constant, just as a C compiler would.  That is, perhaps you're trying to basically write a miniature version of that portion of a C compiler that parses character constants.  If so, that's a completely different (and considerably more involved) problem.

And evidently this *is* what you're trying to do.  See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50542387/pass-a-string-to-ascii-c-language/50543121#50543121).

Comment: I'm doing a C compiler, and it's because that i want the last option. I have to pass char *c1 = " '\000' " to ASCII. The char is stored in a string, and i have to pass the char to ASCII Code. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

So you're trying to write a simple [*lexical analyzer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis).  The syntax of a character constant in C is a single quote, followed by a thing that can go inside, followed by a single quote.  The thing that can go inside is either a single character, or an escape sequence.  An escape sequence is a `\` character followed either by a single character like `n`, or by one to three octal digits.  (There are also hexadecimal escapes, and multi-character character constants, but we'll probably want to ignore those for now.)

So you'll need to write code that can handle all of these possibilities.  In pseudocode, it might look something like this:

```
if first character is `'`, step over it
else error

if next character is not '\', it's the character code we want

else if next character is '\', we have an escape sequence; skip over it and...

    if next character is 'n', character code we want is '\n'
    else if next character is 'r', character code we want is '\r'
    else if next character is 't', character code we want is '\t'
    else if next character is a digit:
        read 1-3 digits
        convert from octal
        that's the character code we want

finally, if next character is `'`, step over it
else error
```

When people write lexical analyzers for real, they usually use a program to help them, such as [`lex`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_(software)) or [`flex`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_(software)).  But it's also a great learning exercise to write your own, by hand, like this.

Comment: In the third if-else case nested inside the if-else, then we can use `atoi` or `strtol`.

Comment: `strtol` maybe.  Definitely not `atoi`.

Comment: @SteveSummit thank you mate. One more question, in third else if, how i convert into a char? i read the 3 digits, but how i store that in a char?

Comment: You can either use `strtol`, or do it by hand: have a variable that starts out containing 0, and then each time you see another digit, take your previous number, multiply it by 8, and add in the digit you just saw.  You will need to subtract `'0'`, to convert character values to digit values.

Comment: When i use strtol: strtol("'\127'",&p,10) the result is always 0.

Comment: @JoãoCastilho (1) What would you expect `strtol("abc123", ...)` to do? (If you think it should ignore `abc` and return 123, go back and read [the documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) again.) (2) Character constants like `'\123'` are base **eight**.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the ASCII code of any character in a string, you can literally just index into the array like so:

```
char *foo = "asdf";
char bar = foo[3];
// bar == 'f'
```

Comment: Well ok it is and it isn't. `foo` is most definitely a pointer, but the pointer happens to point to memory which the programmer can play with. However, the compiler will understand that you want an array, so `sizeof` will give the total size of memory that gets allocated if `sizeof` is used in the same scope as the declaration.

Comment: You would be semantically correct, but for the sake of this question, I don't think the distinction is relevant - do you?

Comment: I want the last option. I'm doing a C Compiler and the the char 'a' is stored in a string. I want to get the ASCII Code of the char 'a'. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by syntactically wrong, but I see your point. I'll edit it out. I'm not sure the attitude is necessary though

Comment: I'm not sure what attitude you're referring to.

Comment: @JoãoCastilho sorry I interpreted your question wrong. I think this is all you need.

Comment: @dualscyther thanks for the answer. But if the string is " '\123' " and i want the ascii code of '\123' ('\123' in C is a char)?

Comment: `"'\123'"` is still a three-character string and `"'\123'"[1]` is `'\123'`.

Comment: Do you mean that the string is literally [',\,1,2,3,'] (disregarding the null terminator)? As in, it is 6 characters long?

Comment: @melpomene i've tried that and it didn't worked for me. if i print the "'\123'"[1], the value is \. Same thing to "'\123'"[0] -> '

Comment: @dualscyther yeah, the string is that, but i want to interpret as a char. It's possible?

Comment: @dualscyther Yes.  He's trying to write a compiler.  See the last part of my answer, and his several comments since then.  He wants to convert `"'\\123'"` to 83.

Comment: @JoãoCastilho Then your string is actually `"'\\123'"`, not `"'\123'"`.

Comment: @melpomene yeah, u're right. My mistake. That is possible?